# How to determine the list of absentees(employees) with the list of present,and the master employee list in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I Have two tables employee(name,id) which consists of all the employees and another table reader(id,date) which gives the dates and which employee was present.How do i find the list of absentees within a certain range of dates?

For a particular date i was able to use the command:

```
SELECT DISTINCT employee.id,reader.dat FROM employee,reader
        WHERE employee.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM reader WHERE dat = '2011-01-18' )
        AND reader.dat='2011-01-18';
```

Comment: Do you want a list of employees who were absent all of the days in the range or on any day in the range?

Comment: I need it for all the days in the range meaning 2011-01-17 to 2011-01-19 meaning who were absent during the 17th,18th,19th....

Answer (score 0):

Use the `BETWEEN` operator with the date range you want.

I.E.,

```
select id 
  from reader 
  where date BETWEEN '2011-01-16' AND '2011-01-19' 
  group by id having count(*) < 4;
```

Comment: I need it for all the days in the range meaning 2011-01-17 to 2011-01-19 meaning who were absent during the 17th,18th,19th....               select employee.id from employee where employee.id NOT IN(select id from reader where date BETWEEN '2011-01-18' AND '2011-01-31' ); gives only the employees who were absent for all three days not on individual days.....

Comment: @Do0m - updated answer for your more specific question. The 'group by' will compress the subquery and count the number of times each id shows up. If it's less than four (or put in the number of days in the BETWEEN range), the id's will show.

Comment: It Does not show up like that at all it only specifies the ones who were absent all the days.